# Change Label Caption based on ListBox selection

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, label

What is the best way to change the Label Name depending of what the user selects in the ListBox.
So far I have this:

```
Private Sub Label6_Click()
    Dim lItem As Long
    For lItem = 0 To ListBox1.ListIndex <> -1
        If ListBox1.Selected(lItem) = "AAA" Or "BBB" Then
            Me.Label6.Caption = "Select Graphite"
        Else
            Me.Label6.Caption = "Select Oil System"
        End If
    Next lItem
End Sub
```

Unfortunately its not working, what am I missing?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your listbox is Multiselect, you don't need to loop through it:

```
Private Sub Label6_Click()
    Dim lItem As Long
    lItem = ListBox1.ListIndex
    If lItem <> -1 then
        Select Case ListBox1.List(lItem)
            Case "AAA", "BBB"
                Me.Label6.Caption = "Select Graphite"
            Case Else
                Me.Label6.Caption = "Select Oil System"
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there also a way to auto update Label6? As of right know i have to manually click on it to show the update.